# Is DATALENGTH() in SQL Server substitute for LENGTH() in Oracle

Tags: sql-server

In Microsoft SQL Server function I have variables declared as float datatype

```
Declare @variable1 float, @variable2 float, @variable3 float;
```

I am storing following value in my variable1

```
SET @variable1 = DATALENGTH(@variable2) - DATALENGTH(@variable3);
```

As DATALENGTH stores results in Byte.. In the above case what will be the datatype of result stored in @variable1

What will be the impact on datatypes of these variables

I need to migrate the Length() functionality from Oracle to SQL Server

Thanks for the help !

Comment: Are you looking for `LEN` in sql-server?

Comment: With both variables being `FLOAT`, each 8 bytes long, `@variable1` will either always be `NULL` (if either variable is `NULL`) or `0` (if neither is). So that's probably not what you're after. Nor is `LEN` necessarily correct in this case, because that implicitly converts the `FLOAT` values to strings first, when you almost certainly want to convert them explicitly to control the output, through `CONVERT` or `FORMAT`.

Comment: Datatypes like float, decimal, int all have a fixed storage size, so it seems you have taken a wrong path in your migration. LEN() in TSQL is a string function that returns the number of characters (ignoring trailing blanks). As posted your question makes little sense - and it is certainly difficult to understand your goal with code involving float datatypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question title says...

> Is DATALENGTH() in SQL Server substitute for LENGTH() in Oracle

Suggesting you have a working query in Oracle, that you'd like to run in SQL Server. To answer that part alone, would be as follows...

- LEN() would be the SQL Server equivalent of LENGTH from Oracle.
- DATALENGTH would be the SQL Server equivalent of LENGTHB from Oracle.

Both accept input as a string. LEN() will give you the length of a string by character count, whereas DATELENGTH will give you the length of a string by byte count. For example, in the case of nvarchar data, your byte length would be double your character length. This is because nvarhcar uses 2 bytes to store one character instead of 1 byte for varchar.

However, your examples use `FLOAT` data types. On the surface, it seems to be acceptable to use `LEN` or `DATALENGTH`, as the `FLOAT` value is implicitly converted to a string, and you get a result you expect.

However, as Jeroen Mostert points out, this may not always be the case...

> To see why this is potentially a problem, or at least needlessly confusing without an explicit conversion, consider LEN(0.0000001E0), which is 6, since the implicit conversion gives 1e-007. LENGTH(0.0000001E0) in Oracle is 8.

Comment: The issue is not that either function won't *work* on `FLOAT`, just that the result may not be what is expected. To be precise, `LEN` indeed does not operate on `FLOAT` values, it only operates on strings. But since there is an implicit conversion from `FLOAT` to every character type, any function that takes a string can be passed a `FLOAT` without complaint. To see why this is potentially a problem, or at least needlessly confusing without an *explicit* conversion, consider `LEN(0.0000001E0)`, which is 6, since the implicit conversion gives `1e-007`. `LENGTH(0.0000001E0)` in Oracle is 8.

Comment: Those are valid points, and something the OP should take into consideration.